# Come tradurre: ticket (support ticket)

Tags: word-usage, translation

Come posso tradurre in italiano **Support ticket**?

Contesto: per alcune applicazioni e' possibile 'aprire un ticket' per avere segnalare un problema o richiedere aiuto.

Può andare **Richiesta di supporto?**

Grazie!

Comment: A parte tutto, non stai chiedendo *ticket*, ma proprio *support ticket* (anche perché “supporto” in italiano non ha lo stesso senso di *support* in inglese; guarda [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/supporto/)).

Comment: Si ma nella maggior parte dei casi viene dato come ticket. Per esempio: open a ticket - close a ticket. Ho aggiunto support per dare un'idea del contesto. Non vedo comunque il motivo per dare un voto negativo a una semplice domanda..

Comment: Io non ho dato un voto negativo: sottolineo solo che, visto che *ticket* in inglese ha numerosi sensi, da “biglietto” a “multa”, non ha molto senso formulare la domanda generica “Come posso tradurre in italiano Ticket?”. E che *support* non si traduce “supporto” (se non stai parlando di mensole   :-) ).

Comment: Dare voti positivi tanto per “bilanciare” voti negativi di cui non cogli il motivo non è esattamente nello spirito di SE: un voto positivo significa esplicitamente “This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear”. Da qualche commento ho l'impressione che secondo qualcuno le tue domande mostrano poco “research effort”. Tornando a noi, comunque, “richiesta di assistenza” mi suona bene.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essendo nel settore, ed avendo fatto di queste traduzioni in alcune occasioni, credo che una buona traduzione possa essere **Richiesta di assistenza**, che puoi accorciare alla sola parola **Assistenza** dove lo ritieni opportuno. Ad esempio, potresti usare:

- Support ticket: Richiesta di assistenza
- Open a ticket: Nuova richiesta / Nuova assistenza
- Close ticket: Chiudi assistenza

Scegliere se mantenere l'accento su *Richiesta* o se spostarlo sulla parte di *Assistenza*, penso dipenda da quale traduzione tu ritieni sia più chiara per l'utilizzatore finale.